# Non https web sites display the content of https sites

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, cpanel

We have a cpanel server that hosts some web sites. we have 2 hosts that use SSL. When I open a non SSL website with http:// everything is ok but when I type https:// , it shows the contents of one of the SSL websites instead of displaying not found error!!
Usually the first one which is defined in httpd.conf. 
I also signed up in cPanel forum, but I do not know how to post a new question!! I cannot find post a question or new post or something like that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really confusing. It would be better if you can edit and elaborate your question. Still let me guess your question and answer it.

Your cPanel server has hosted more than one websites, out of them only two have SSL certificate. Let me guess those two sites as abc.com and xyz.com. Now if I have understood your question properly, when you try to access 123.com (which is non HTTPS website) with HTTPS it is showing content of abc.com.

If yes, then this case refers to SSL misconfiguration. To solve this issue, SSL certificate should be installed properly on both websites and only those two sites can be accessible with HTTPS. It is advisable to use SSL Certificate checker for both sites to know whether SSL is installed properly or not.

Comment: Dear @Gunjan Tripathi, thank you for your reply. yep my question was exactly as you described. I found the solution here: "https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1150Docs/SSL+FAQ+and+Troubleshooting" where it is written "My certificate installed, but visitors who try to securely...."

Comment: Yes they are. Thanks for your time and help.